# How to set the column_width for table while using rails prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

This is my prawn code

```
table1 = [["Time duration selected", "Driving Time", "Stop Time", "Productivity", "Stop Count", "Max Speed (km/h)", "Average Speed (km/h)", "Distance Travelled (km)"]]

table(table1)
```

This code creates a row.. But i need to specify column width here... so how to set the column width?

Answer (score 11):

Two ways width can be mentioned.

First, `table tablename,:column_widths => {0 => 70,1 => 60,2 => 60,3 => 60,4 => 60,5 => 70,6 => 70,7 => 70}`

This table contains 8 columns.

Secondly, you set the width of the whole table `table tablename,:width => 350`

Comment: The docs say you can use an Array but I had to change this to the Hash syntax you suggested.